# VScode: Same terminal output over multiple columns

Tags: visual-studio-code

I generally run a program where the output is not very wide but I find myself constantly scrolling up to see previous output - it runs on a timer. I would like to use up more of my monitor by having the output flow over three columns instead of just one big one with a lot of wasted screen real estate.

Is there any setting or extension in vscode that allows this?

Comment: which terminal program do you know that has this functionality

Comment: @rioV8 None that I know of currently.